# Making 2 version of Janino work together for Junit Tests using Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, drools, janino

I am working on a spark program which uses Drools internally. The code works fine. Now, I am writing test cases to test the drools code. Because of this bug https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-329, I had to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
  <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.16</version>
 </dependency>
```

then the JVM argument for jacoco testing

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <argLine>-Ddrools.dialect.java.compiler=JANINO</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

After adding that Spark test cases started failing as they have dependency on

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
  <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

So, I commented out the Drools Tests and 2.5.16 janino dependency in POM. Now the Spark code is working fine. How can we make sure that both Janino 2.5.16 and Janino 3.0.8 coexist together during Maven test build that way both Drools tests as well as Spark tests pass?

Here is the Drools code that I am using

```
public static void applyRules(ResultObj obj) {
        try {
            KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
            kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource( "rules/rules.drl", DroolsPreprocessor.class),
                    ResourceType.DRL );
            if ( kbuilder.hasErrors() ) {
                System.err.println( kbuilder.getErrors().toString() );
            }
            StatelessKieSession session = kbuilder.newKieBase().newStatelessKieSession();
            session.execute(obj);
            System.out.println("Reached the end ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the Drools dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

With Janino 2.5.16 Spark is not happy it throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/InternalCompilerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.JavaCode$.variable(javaCode.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.JavaCode$.isNullVariable(javaCode.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.$anonfun$genCode$3(Expression.scala:145)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenContext.$anonfun$generateExpressions$1(CodeGenerator.scala:1170)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenContext.generateExpressions(CodeGenerator.scala:1170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.createCode(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.create(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.generate(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.createCodeGeneratedObject(Projection.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.createCodeGeneratedObject(Projection.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CodeGeneratorWithInterpretedFallback.createObject(CodeGeneratorWithInterpretedFallback.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRecordToRowConverter.<init>(KafkaRecordToRowConverter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRelation.<init>(KafkaRelation.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
```

If I don't add Janino 2.5.16 dependency I get the following errors for testing

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:302)
at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:860)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)
at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:436)
at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:420)
at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:61)
at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:109)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileAll(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1471)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.wireAllRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:950)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addPackage(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:938)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addPackageFromDrl(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:543)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addKnowledgeResource(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:743)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:2288)
at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:2277)
```

Comment: What version of Drools? That's pretty old bug that affected pretty old versions.

Comment: That is the thing this is Drools version 7 which should not have that bug. But still it does while executing the tests

Comment: Then it's a different bug that has a similar manifestation and you're trying to apply the wrong fix to it. What is the actual error caused by the "bug"?

Comment: I have added the spark exception when Janino 2.5.16 is added, will add the other exception

Comment: What happens if you don't add the Janino 2 dependency? you already have Janino 3, that should satisfy the compiler's need if you really need to use the Janino compiler.

Comment: added that exception also @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas